# How to fix "mount_smbfs: server connection failed: No such file or directory"

Tags: smb

Use command "mount_smbfs //username:password@server/Shared /Volumes" to connect with Windows Server, but it return with "mount_smbfs: server connection failed: No such file or directory"

```
>>mount_smbfs //username:password@server/Shared /Volumes
mount_smbfs: server connection failed: No such file or directory
```

I can not use "Finder->Go->Connect to Server" neither. Each server I connect to as "smb://server" would return an error "There was a problem connecting to the server".
Beside, I could ping the server successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that SMB didn't work in My Mac, and someone give a workaround to fix it.
[You can visit it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257836/mac-mini-cant-connect-to-my-corporate-smb-server-was-working-some-days-ago/262136#262136?newreg=d83d3569497d4d40aa594a6cafa12de0)